# I want matlab to read a comma separated txt file with 100s of columns

Tags: matlab

On http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html, I can see the suggestion:

```
fileID = fopen('data3.csv');
C = textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f %f','Delimiter',',',...
'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);
fclose(fileID);
celldisp(C)
```

Not sure if textscan can also .txt but I can't really write out 100s of '%f's. Is there a way to do this by giving textscan the dimensions of the mtx in my .txt file? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. As the documentation states: `C = textscan(str,formatSpec,N)` reads string data using the `formatSpec` `N` times, where `N` is a positive integer. This will read `N` rows (assuming `formatSpec` corresponds to a whole row). You can also [skip the remainder of a line](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#btg0ke2) and [read or skip quoted strings and numeric fields](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#bucjrwb-10).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file that is only numbers, and the text is comma separated (.csv), then you can use csvread:

```
num_headerlines = 1
C = csvread('C:\users\smith\Documents\data3.csv', num_headerlines, 0)
```

The last two arguments here are the row and column to begin reading, and unlike most everything else in MATLAB, they are 0-indexed, so if you want to start on the first column, you pass a `0`, and if you want to start on the second row, you pass a `1`.  This will read as many columns as you have, without needed a long format specifier.